# Is the set of all polynomials dense in the set of all continuous functions that maps from a compact set to reals

Tags: weierstrass-approximation

Let $C$ be a set of all continuous functions that map from a compact set to the reals. Is the set of all polynomials dense in $C$, with respect to the sup metric?

Can I show that by using the Stone-Weierstrauss Theorem? Since I can find a sequence of polynomials that converge uniformly to any continuous function, if I take the closure of the set of polynomials, do I get the entire set of continuous functions?

Comment: No, because Stone-Weierstrass only applies to compact sets. $e^x$ is not uniformly approximable by polynomials.

Comment: Isn't the set of all continuous functions compact?

Comment: Dense with respect to which topology?

Comment: You should really define the topology/metric/spaces involved here.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Updated

Comment: Which interval do you have ? $\mathbb R$ or $[a,b]$ ?

Comment: @Peter Does it matter? I meant to ask $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What's the general metric on the set $C(\Bbb R,\Bbb R)$?

Comment: @tryingtosolve I think it matters. In a closed interval, we can approximate every continous function arbitary close by a polynomial. I don't think this is the case , if we allow $\mathbb R$ as an interval.

Comment: What is the "general metric"? $L^{\infty}$?

Comment: @user296602 ... which is not a metric on the set of continuous functions, by the way.

Comment: @user296602 I meant the sup metric.

Comment: @tryingtosolve That is not a metric, because continuous functions $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ are not bounded.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Is that why I need compactness?

Comment: Updated the question again.

Comment: Assuming you're using the usual topology induced by the $\sup$ metric, the answer is now yes.